# Jersey POST method argument as ClassObject

Tags: java, json, jersey

I've been using jersey for a while and I just implemented a POST method which gets a Json as argument. However I would like it to function like this:

```
 // The json class to be used and returned
    @XmlRootElement
    public class Container 
    {
        private boolean isOk;
        private String message;

        public Container() {}

        public boolean getOk()
        {
            return this.isOk;
        }   

        public void setOk(boolean isOk)
        {
            this.isOk = isOk;
        }
    }

    // A service
    @Path("json/test")
    public class TestService 
    {
        @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Container readAndReturnMessage(Container receivedJson)
        {
            doSomething(receivedJson.getMessage());
            return receivedJson;
        }   
    }
```

Unfortunately this isnt working. All of Container variables are null, even though there is nothing wrong with the raw json passed to the service. What is the approach here, do I need to take a String as argument instead and use Jackson/Gson to deserialize?

Answer (score 2):

In case you have not added any header, you need to add **Content-Type** header with your **POST** request.
As, your application is consuming **application/json** you need to add
**Content-Type: application/json** with your POST request.

If your request body is of form:
{
  "Container": {
    "isOk": "true",
    "message": "New message"
  }
}
You will get null values.

The request body should be of form:
{
    "isOk": "true",
    "message": "New message"
}
This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add getters and setters for your `Container` class.

upd. [Here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch06_02.htm) are convetions for creating Java Beans. See namings section. By the way I failed with boolean fields. The best way:

```
boolean ok;

public boolean isOk(){
   return this.ok;
}

/* if setter is required */
public setOk(boolean ok){
   this.ok = ok;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, there are getters & setters. I just forgot to add them.

Comment: if the variable name is `isOk` then getter must be `getIsOk()` and setter `setIsOk(boolean isOk)

Comment: Do variables really depend on their getters and setters in this case?